# C# TCP connection headers

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I'm trying create program detect DDOS and block their IP, but I use TCP proxy so I cant get real IP :( They send header that contains real ip, but how I can get it? My proxy send header X-Real-IP that contains real IP. I'm currently using this small code get all TCP connections:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.listView1.Items.Clear();
    IPGlobalProperties properties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
    TcpConnectionInformation[] connections = properties.GetActiveTcpConnections();
    foreach (TcpConnectionInformation c in connections)
    {
        ListViewItem listViewItemConnectionInformation = new ListViewItem(c.RemoteEndPoint.Address.ToString()); //from ip
        listViewItemConnectionInformation.SubItems.Add(c.LocalEndPoint.Address.ToString()); //to ip
        listViewItemConnectionInformation.SubItems.Add(c.RemoteEndPoint.Port.ToString()); //from port
        listViewItemConnectionInformation.SubItems.Add(c.LocalEndPoint.Port.ToString()); //to port
        listViewItemConnectionInformation.SubItems.Add(""); //real ip
        this.listView1.Items.Add(listViewItemConnectionInformation);
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be talking about HTTP? TCP-level operations cannot get you HTTP headers.

Comment: @usr Oh..? There is no way get TCP Proxy user real ip? :D

Comment: Not at the TCP level, no. TCP does not know what a proxy is. You seem to be talking about HTTP headers. TCP does not have headers.

Comment: @usr Oh OK :( No way track HTTP requests?

Comment: There is always a way :P. You could capture all traffic, then parse the TCP and HTTP headers.

Comment: @usr Ok :) How I can track them?

Comment: I mean its a fair amount of work. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12458/SharpPcap-A-Packet-Capture-Framework-for-NET

Comment: I'm guessing the IP Addresses are being proxied at some sort of  load balancer level. Could you apply your DDOS detection there? Seemingly this problem has already been solved and I don't know if creating a new solution for DDOS detection is the correct path.